# Multiple Forms with multiple Models - OnPost Model is null

Tags: c#, razor-pages

Added the handler, I can call the correct method, but my model is always null. I'm sure i'm not assigning the model correctly. I am sending 3 models to the form to populate the tables for check box permission selection. When I click the save button, the model is blank. I do prefer 1 save button but tried to assign base previledges to the 1 button, and other employee and user tables the remaining buttons.

```
@page
@model MosaicTitlePro.Pages.User.RolesPermissionsModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Modify Permissions for ";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/Mosaic/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div class="container">
    <h3>Modify Permissions for Role: @Model.basePermissions.RoleName</h3>
    <hr />
    <h4>Base Permissions </h4>
    <form method="post" asp-page-handler="base" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input asp-for="@Model.basePermissions.RoleId" type="hidden" />
        <table class="table table-striped" id="permissionTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Type
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Permission
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Status
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.basePermissions.RoleClaims.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input asp-for="@Model.basePermissions.RoleClaims[i].Type" type="hidden" />
                            @Model.basePermissions.RoleClaims[i].Type
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input asp-for="@Model.basePermissions.RoleClaims[i].Value" type="hidden" />
                            @Model.basePermissions.RoleClaims[i].Value
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-check m-1">
                                <input asp-for="@Model.basePermissions.RoleClaims[i].Selected" class="form-check-input" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button type="submit" id="save" class="btn bg-primary">
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
            Save
        </button>

    </form>

    <h4>HR Permissions </h4>
    <table class="table table-striped" id="permissionTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Type
                </th>
                <th>
                    Permission
                </th>
                <th>
                    Status
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.employeePermissions.RoleClaims.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="@Model.employeePermissions.RoleClaims[i].Type" type="hidden" />
                        @Model.basePermissions.RoleClaims[i].Type
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="@Model.employeePermissions.RoleClaims[i].Value" type="hidden" />
                        @Model.basePermissions.RoleClaims[i].Value
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-check m-1">
                            <input asp-for="@Model.employeePermissions.RoleClaims[i].Selected" class="form-check-input" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <h4>Users</h4>
    <table class="table table-striped" id="permissionTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Type
                </th>
                <th>
                    Permission
                </th>
                <th>
                    Status
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.userPermissions.RoleClaims.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="@Model.userPermissions.RoleClaims[i].Type" type="hidden" />
                        @Model.basePermissions.RoleClaims[i].Type
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="@Model.userPermissions.RoleClaims[i].Value" type="hidden" />
                        @Model.basePermissions.RoleClaims[i].Value
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-check m-1">
                            <input asp-for="@Model.userPermissions.RoleClaims[i].Selected" class="form-check-input" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>


</div>
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using MosaicTitlePro.Helpers;
using MosaicTitlePro.Models.ViewModels;
using MosaicTitlePro.Permission;

namespace MosaicTitlePro.Pages.User
{
    public class RolesPermissionsModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

        public RolesPermissionsModel(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            _roleManager = roleManager;
        }
        public PermissionViewModel basePermissions { get; set; }
        public PermissionViewModel employeePermissions { get; set; }
        public PermissionViewModel userPermissions { get; set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync(string Id)
        {
            string roleId = Id;
            basePermissions = await GetRolePermissionsAsync<Permissions.Base>(roleId);
            employeePermissions = await  GetRolePermissionsAsync<Permissions.Employee>(roleId);
            userPermissions =  await GetRolePermissionsAsync<Permissions.Base>(roleId);
        }

        public async Task<RedirectToActionResult> OnPostBaseAsync(PermissionViewModel model)
        {
            await PutRolePermissionsAsync(model);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { roleId = model.RoleId });
        }

        protected async Task<PermissionViewModel> GetRolePermissionsAsync<T>(string roleId)
        {
            var model = new PermissionViewModel();
            var allPermissions = new List<RoleClaimsViewModel>();
            allPermissions.GetPermissions(typeof(T), roleId);
            var role = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(roleId);
            model.RoleId = roleId;
            model.RoleName = role.Name;
            var claims = await _roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(role);
            var allClaimValues = allPermissions.Select(a => a.Value).ToList();
            var roleClaimValues = claims.Select(a => a.Value).ToList();
            var authorizedClaims = allClaimValues.Intersect(roleClaimValues).ToList();
            foreach (var permission in allPermissions)
            {
                if (authorizedClaims.Any(a => a == permission.Value))
                {
                    permission.Selected = true;
                }
            }
            model.RoleClaims = allPermissions;
            return model;
        }

        protected async Task PutRolePermissionsAsync(PermissionViewModel model)
        {
            var role = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(model.RoleId);
            var claims = await _roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(role);
            foreach (var claim in claims)
            {
                await _roleManager.RemoveClaimAsync(role, claim);
            }
            var selectedClaims = model.RoleClaims.Where(a => a.Selected).ToList();
            foreach (var claim in selectedClaims)
            {
                await _roleManager.AddPermissionClaim(role, claim.Value);
            }
           
        }
    }
}
```

```
    public class PermissionViewModel
    {
        public string RoleId { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        public IList<RoleClaimsViewModel> RoleClaims { get; set; }
    }

    public class RoleClaimsViewModel
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
    }
```